# Atomineer and documenting methods with generic constraints

Tags: c#, generics, atomineer

I'm using Atomineer to auto generate documentation comments in my code. All seems to be working fine except I'm running into an issue with getting doc comments on methods with multiple generic constraints:

Comments will auto-generate on a method with one constraint like this:

`Public void Test<T>() where T : IEntity`

...but, when I have more than one constraint like this, documentation comments are not generated and no error appears in the Output.

`Public void Test<T>() where T : class, IEntity`

I could not find a solution in the Atomineer User Manual.

In this solution I have many generic methods with multiple constraints that I need documentation for.  I can manualy enter them or I can remove the constraints, generate the documentation, and then replace them but there are so many I'd be at it for days.

Maybe there is a configuration solution that I'm unaware of and overlooked or is missing from the user manual.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest emailing Atomineer support directly if you have a question - we're always happy to help and eager to know if there is anything Atomineer could do better.

I believe the issue you reported has been fixed - but if not, please just send us an example so we can reproduce the issue and resolve it for you.